# Move GeoTIFF file to another coordinate of lat and lon

Tags: qgis, raster, srtm, move

I have a GeoTIFF file that corresponds to terrain data (SRTM 3-arc data).
I need to do 3 things;

1. Crop a specific area of ​​the raster and
2. Literally move the raster to another coordinate of lat and lon.
3. Save it into new GeoTIFF

For example, if it were a set of islands, cut only one, and move it to another location in the world.

I have QGIS for iMac.

Comment: you could use gdal_translate (https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) -projwin option to extract a subset of your raster to a format like a bitmap (-of BMP) which will create a world file (.bpw) which you can edit the parameters manually then convert the bitmap to a geoTIFF with gdal_translate -of GTIFF. I know it's a bit of a hack but it works. You have no tags or mention of an API or programming language to offer a code solution; GDAL_Translate is available through QGIS as Raster::Translate.

Comment: Have you checked the answers of previous questions on this site?  What you are asking for was answered many times on separate questions. Please do your research first and if you stuck somewhere during the process please give us a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

I got the first step, crop a specific area of ​​the raster with:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -projwin -17.1 28.725 -15.998 27.895 srtm_33_07.tif final.tif
```

Then I convert GeoTIFF file to BMP with:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -of BMP final.tif out.bmp
```

and it generates that error ->

> Input file size is 1322, 996
>   0ERROR 1: Attempt to create BMP dataset with an illegal
>   data type (Int16), only Byte supported by the format.

I tried this other way, but it doesn't generate the .bpw file

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -of BMP -ot Byte final.tif output.bmp
```

The file that contains the information "output.bmp.aux.xml", does not display it in lat/lon coordinates ->

> GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
>      -1.7100000000000001e+01,  8.3333333333333339e-04,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  2.8725000000000001e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -8.3333333333333339e-04
>     
>       Area
>     
>     
>       -3.27680000000000E+04
>       Gray

I think I would first have to solve this (I tried several things, but I can't solve it). Then I will enter the "new coordinates" where to locate this 3-arc SRTM data fragment in the * bmp.aux.xml file and then i will convert it to GeoTIFF.

Any indication regarding this??...